# How to show result value like this using ajax post requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to show result value like this  ?

When change select tag to Eg: `<option value="3">THREE</option>`

i want to show  result in `<span id="myplace2"></span>`

But if change selete to Eg:  `<option value="4">THREE</option>`

i want to show  result in `<span id="myplace4"></span>`

How can i do that ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    <select id="number" name="number" OnChange="fn_test1()" >
      <option selected="" value="">SELECT</option>
      <option value="1">ONE</option>
      <option value="2">TWO</option>
      <option value="3">THREE</option>
      <option value="4">FOUR</option>
    </select>
<?PHP
    for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
        {
?>
    <span id="myplace<?PHP echo $i; ?>"></span><br>
<?PHP
        }
?>
</form>

<script>
function fn_test1() {
    $('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test_mm16.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).show();
                    $('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your two examples don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use jquery in order to retrieve the value of selected item. Your code could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn_test1() {
   var selected = $("#number option:selected").val(); //Get the value of selected item (like '1', '2');
   setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax(
           {
            //Put here url, type, ...
            success: function(data) {
                $("#myplace" + selected).show();
                $("#myplace" + selected).html(data); //Put the output inside the right element
           }
        })
   }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change visibility of parts of the page when the user changes selection from the dropdown box? Why do you need ajax for this?

```
function fn_test1() {
    $('.mp').hide();
    $('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).show();
}
```

Then add `class="mp"` to the `myplace` `<span>` elements.

Unless of course you're planning to add dynamic content to the spans. In that case:

- You appear to be using the same PHP script for both the main page and ajax calls, which is unconventional - ajax responses should be in a data-interchange format such as XML or JSON, not HTML.
- The `data` variable is only declared in the success handler, so the first usage of it isn't working as you probably intended.
- What if the user wants to refresh the contents of the span without refreshing the whole page or changing selection?